# nested ajax request does not work properly

Tags: ajax, sync

I have the following code, where I am trying to execute a nested ajax request to display eventually a dynamically created bootstrap carousel. But I think something goes wrong, because those two requests are not syncronized.
the `console.log(i)` displays `i=0,1,2` and after that it gets inside the nested ajax request where `console.log("i equals "+i)` returns `i equals 3`. As a result I cannot update the global variables inside the inner ajax reuest. I have already tried to add `async : false` but it gives me a warning. Do you have any other suggestions on the matter?

```
<script>
    var htmlMainSliderIndicatios="";
function LoadMainSliderContents (){
        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Container?$expand=Frame_id&$filter = Frame_id/Position eq 1",
             method: "GET",
             headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
             success: function (data) {
              for(var i=0; i<data.d.results.length;i++){
                console.log(i)
                $.ajax({
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ContentsTranslation?$select=Title0,Subtitle,Content,LanguageValue,StatusValue,Content_id/StatusValue,Content_id/Conta_idId,Content_id/PictureXS&$expand = Content_id&$filter = Content_id/Conta_idId eq "+data.d.results[i].Id+" and LanguageValue eq 'en' and StatusValue  eq 'ongoing'",                                                          
                     method: "GET",
                     headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                     success: function (tasks) {
                        console.log("i equals "+i)                  
                        $.each(tasks.d.results, function(bindex, task) {
                        });
                     },
                     error: function (data) {
                        console.log("fail");
                    }
                });//end of inner ajax
    }//end of outter for
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("fail");
        }
        });
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("LoadMainSliderContents");

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

What globals do you want to set?

Ajax calls are like giving 3 people the assignment:

- Get me a coffee,
- Get me a donut
- and Get me a paper.

**You do not have control over when they return.**

`async:false` can help, but will take longer to finish..

- because the donut guy now has to wait for the coffee guy to return,
- and the paper guy won't leave until the donut is delivered.

What error message do you get with `async:false` ?

If you need Order you need to tell those guys what Order number they have

**and NOT rely on information from the outer loop**

1. Get me a coffee, you are number 1
2. Get me a donut, you are number 2
3. Get me a paper,, you are number 3

Then when a guy returns you can ask his number and you know what task he had.

J5 JX

Comment: This great post has helped me understand Ajax a lot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call