# Which ajax code runs first

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, ajax

I have two ajax call in my jquery code, I would need one value from the first one to be used in second ajax call. But I observed that the second ajax code is running first.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://test/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('abc')/items?$select=Title,sub/Title&$expand=sub",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
        for(var i=0;i<data.d.results.length;i++)
        {
          if(data.d.results[i].Title == versionTitle)
          {
          varSubsystem = data.d.results[i].Sub.Title;
          }         
        }                  
        },
        error: function ( xhr, status, error) {
      alert( " xhr.responseText: " + xhr.responseText + " //status: " + status + " //Error: "+error ); 
        }
    }); 


$.ajax({
        url: "https://test/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Mapping')/items?$select=Title,Team/Title,Sub/Title,Subsys/Title,Subsys/Team_x0020_Member&$expand=Sub,Team,Subsys",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {          
        for(var i=0;i<data.d.results.length;i++)
        {
          if(data.d.results[i].Sub.Title == varSubsystem && data.d.results[i].Team.Title == teamName)
          {
          owner = data.d.results[i].Subsys.Team_x0020_Member;
          }

        }

            console.log(data.d.results);
        },
        error: function ( xhr, status, error) {
      alert( " xhr.responseText: " + xhr.responseText + " //status: " + status + " //Error: "+error ); 
        }
    });
```

How would I make sure that the second ajax code runs after the first one?

Comment: You put it in the success of the first one or use promises (as you do with all asynchronous javascript code..)

Answer (score 1):

The A in Ajax means Asynchronous. So as Robert says, chain with Promises or put the second call inside the Success Callback function of the first

- [Ajax explained with coffee, a donut and a newspaper](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164913/nested-ajax-request-does-not-work-properly/164916#164916)
- [template code explaining Ajax Callbacks and Promises](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/165599/rest-call-to-get-list-not-working/165625#165625)
- [Ajax without jQuery in plain vanilla Javacript code](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/165599/rest-call-to-get-list-not-working/165625#165625)

Note: You could solve your problem by setting the property `async:false` in the first Ajax call... it makes the call NOT asynchronous. Only use it when you know what it does (or do not care about performance)